# Django / Static Files or images are not loading properly

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-static

I apologize if the error was posted earlier but I have not been able to work this through. I have the following django project structure.

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── rango
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── static
│   ├── duck.jpg
│   └── images
│       └── duck.jpg
├── tango
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
└── templates
    └── rango
        └── index.html
```

My INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and the STATIC FILE settings are as follows.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango',
)
```

and

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Rango says...</h1>
        hello <strong>{{ boldmessage }}</strong><br/>
        <img src="{% static "duck.jpg" %}" alt="Picture of Duck" /><br/>       
        <a href="/rango/about">About</a><br/>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
# File: urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^about',views.about,name='about'),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I am not sure why it does not work.

-- EDIT --
I am not sure what happened but this works after making the following changes which looks essentially the same to me though

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
print os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

---

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: next time clean up your question. e.g. don't show us your `*.pyc` file, indent correctly, and remove print statement

Comment: are you in `DEBUG = False` mode?

Comment: What is your `STATIC_ROOT` value?

Comment: I did not set STATIC_ROOT as it was a development version I believe from the tutorial. But STATIC_PATH = STATIC_ROOT, let me set it.

STATIC_PATH=~/tango/static

Comment: Can you try with the following settings? https://github.com/9gix/djskel/blob/master/project_name/settings.py#L43-L68 You can ignore the `MEDIA` settings

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Check my edits above, I am not sure why it works but it works after this changes, which looks the same as before.

Comment: Figured out I had named STATICFILES_DIRS as  STATICFILES_DIR, I am sorry for the trouble caused

Comment: Great to hear that it works. A minor typo solve the problem :)